# where is the variable scope in es6 module?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have 3 classes name `A.js` `B.js` and `Util.js`

Util.js:

just one  static function for get the data and store it, then it dont need to make a request everytime.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
let store={};
class Util  {
    static storeGet(url,cb){
        //console.log(store);
        if(store[url]){
            cb(store[url])
        }else{
            $.get(url, (data) => {
                store[url]=data;
                cb(data);
            });
        }
    }   
}
export default Util;
```

my `A` and `B` is look like that

```
    ....
    import Util from './util';
    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {stories: []};
      }

      componentDidMount() {
            Util.storeGet(Api.getList(), (result) => {
                const data = result;
                if (data) {
                   this.setState((prevState) => ({
                        stories: data.stories
                    }));
                }
            });
        }

      render() {
   ...
```

so now I can import this class from `A` or `B`,

and both `A` and `B` works fine and it seems share the `store` variable.

but we know `A` or `B` can't access `store` directly.

so I want to know where's the `store` variable scope actually?

why cant access `store` directly but by the function `storeGet`??

Comment: How do you use it at A and B? Show me your code, please

Comment: `store` has module scope. It is private to the module. However, it can be accessed from a public (exported) function. The principle is identical to a JS function accessing some private variable it closes over.

Comment: if you set store as a member of the Util class like `Util.store = {};`, you'll be able to access it in the same way as storeget

Comment: @torazaburo Sounds like you should post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

All variables declared inside an ES6 module are private to that module. Which is good. If you did want to make the `store` variable available to other code directly (probably not a good idea in this case), you change your code like this:

```
export let store = {};
```

And then use it like this:

```
import { store } from './util';
```